# Regular expression login on jQuery form

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a problem with a regular expression. `console.log` shows me the login regular expression isn't respected, but my span doesn't show, my email span works.

I think it's a basic JS/jQuery problem, but I couldn't find the solution.

HTML:

```
<form name="formSignup">
    <fieldset>

        <label for="nom">Nom :</label>
        <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" class="required"  />

        <label for="prenom">Prenom :</label>
        <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom" class="required"  />

        <label for="email">Votre Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="required" onclick="spanHide()"  />

        <label for="username">Login:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="required"  />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required" />

        <input id="Submit1" type="button" value="Login" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" onclick='createuser()' />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
var loginReg= /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

if (email == '') {
    $("#email").after('<span id="errormail" class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
}

if (!loginReg.test(myLogin)) {
    console.log("error");
    $("#username").after('<span id="errorlogin" class="error">only letter + digits plz</span>');
}
if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
    $("#email").after('<span id="errormail" class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
}
```

Comment: This code seems valid to me, I found no errors.

Comment: probably you need to return false from the method to prevent submission

Comment: yes it seems valid, if i replace my #username by #nom it works!

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275372/javascript-regex-should-pass-test-but-appears-to-fail-why

Comment: how do your selectors for 'email' and 'myLogin' look like ?

Comment: var email = oForm.elements["email"].value;
                        var myLogin = oForm.elements["username"].value;